# How to resolve exception "eval failed, request status: error code: 127" in R and Java?

Tags: r, prediction, java

I am using R and Java for displaying prediction.

I have data of 5 hours. I want to predict 5th-hour data from four hours' data (memory with respect to date).
By using 4 hours' data I am creating new collection and inserting the 5th hour's predicted data in a new collection. But I am getting the following error:

```
The Exception is eval failed, request status: error code: 127
org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RserveException: eval failed, request status: error code: 127
at org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RConnection.eval(RConnection.java:233)
at scheduler.scheduler.predictions.getPredictionsofData(predictions.java:45)
at pack.GetCollectionMultithreaded.getPredictionAndInsert(GetCollectionMultithreaded.java:386)
at pack.GetCollectionMultithreaded.runCustomerListAndPredictionEvery5Min(GetCollectionMultithreaded.java:155)
at pack.GetCollectionMultithreaded.main(GetCollectionMultithreaded.java:103)
```

Here is code:

```
public class predictions {

public void getPredictionsofData(DB dbObj){
 FileInputStream fis = null;

 DBCollection network_device_realtime = dbObj.getCollection("mycollectionname");
DBObject return_dobject = null;

// For Network device1 realtime
try{
 List<String> listOfIps = network_device_realtime.distinct("hostId");
 RConnection c = new RConnection(Rhost,Rport);
 c.eval("library(RMongo)");
 c.eval("library(plyr)");
 c.eval("library(randomForest)");
 c.eval(" db <- mongoDbConnect('demo','localhost',27017)");
 for( int i= 0 ;i<listOfIps.size(); i++){
     float my_predicted_date = 0 ;
             BasicDBObject criteria = new BasicDBObject();
     BasicDBObject projections = new BasicDBObject();
     criteria.put("hostId",listOfIps.get(i));
    projections.put("runtimeMillis", 1);
    DBCursor cursor = network_device_realtime.find(criteria,projections).sort(new BasicDBObject("runtimeMillis",-1)).limit(1);
    while(cursor.hasNext()) {   
        BasicDBObject obj = (BasicDBObject) cursor.next();
        my_predicted_date = (float) obj.getDouble("runtimeMillis");
    }
    // Set predict date for testing purpose 
     my_predicted_date = my_predicted_date-(4*60*60*1000);

    // for calculating predictions next 24 hrs
    for(int j = 1; j <= 12 ;j++){
            my_predicted_date = my_predicted_date+(300*1000);//j*60*60*1000calculating next hrs data
        System.out.println("Date Gen in network: " +my_predicted_date);

         c.eval("query <- dbGetQuery(db,'"+network_device_realtime+"','{\"hostId\":\""+listOfIps.get(i)+"\",\"cpuUtilization\":{\"$ne\":\"null\"},\"memoryUtilization\":{\"$ne\":\"NaN\"},\"runtimeMillis\":{\"$ne\":\"null\"}}')");

         c.eval("date <- query$runtimeMillis");
    c.eval("host_id <- query$hostId");
         c.eval("cpu <-  query$cpuUtilization ");
    c.eval("memory <- query$memoryutil");
         c.eval("all_data<-data.frame(cpu,date)");
         c.eval("training<- all_data");

         c.eval("rf_fit<-randomForest(memory~date,data=training)");
         c.eval("df <- data.frame(date="+my_predicted_date+ ")");
         c.eval("predictions<-predict(rf_fit,newdata=new)");
         REXP memory_predictions= c.eval("predictions");
         c.eval("rf_fit<-randomForest(cpu~date,data=training)");
         c.eval("df <- data.frame(date="+my_predicted_date+ ")");
         c.eval("predictions<-predict(rf_fit,newdata=new)");
         REXP cpu_predictions= c.eval("predictions");
         String json = ""; 
         json ="{\"memoryUtilization\":"+ memory_predictions + ",\"cpuUtilization\" : "+ cpu_predictions + ",\"hostId\" : \""+ listOfIps.get(i) + "\",\"runtimeMillis\":"+my_predicted_date+",\"deviceType\":\"snmp\"}";
         return_dobject=(DBObject) JSON.parse(json);
         dbObj.getCollection("prediction").insert(return_dobject);
        }
     }
         c.close();
    }
catch(Exception e){
     System.out.println("ERROR: In Connection to R ");
     System.out.println("The Exception is "+ e.getMessage());
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
}
}//class
```

In this code I am getting error on this line:

```
 c.eval("rf_fit<-randomForest(memory~date,data=training)");
```

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: I got this error because I didn't load a library using `library(libname)`, thus adding the library solve my problem. PS : I know it's not the solution of this question (according to the accepted answer), hope this could helps someone ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception mainly occurs due to data in statement

```
c.eval("rf_fit<-randomForest(memory~date,data=training)");
```

contains null.

This is might be due to bug in your data framing.
Please check it once.

Comment: I will check my data framing statement and query.

Answer (score 5):

To get the proper error message, use this instead of simple eval

```
REXP rResponseObject = rServeConnection.parseAndEval(
    "try(eval("+R_COMMAND_OR_SOURCE_FILE_PATH+"),silent=TRUE)");
if (rResponseObject.inherits("try-error")) {
  LOGGER.error("R Serve Eval Exception : "+rResponseObject.asString());
}
```

This logger prints exact error thrown from R.

Comment: How to configure the logger? Its giving me error LOGGER cannot be resolved. @Anand

Comment: LOGGER is a separate package. Like log4j for java, there are multiple options in R. You can try log4r  . https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/log4r/log4r.pdf. We wrote a util method to wrap each of these logging methods(info, error etc) and called the wrapper methods through out the method, so we can change the logging package to something else later if needed just in one place(like when some other better logging framework comes). @Akki